# .net to Oracle date format issue

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a C# application that's reading data from an Oracle view. The Oracle date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` but from the .net app that format mask throws an error because the time is missing.  I'd like to default the date to `mm/dd/yyyy 12:00 am`.  What's the easiest way to do that?

```
return string.Format("trunc(to_date({0}, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM'), 'DDD')", 
    LeftDateDelimiter + Source + RightDateDelimeter);
```

Comment: What line in c# causes the error? You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` if you know the format you want to parse a string from.

Comment: The format mask I use in the first part of the example above does not throw an error but having the time stamp on the Oracle side is causing issues.  If I change the format mask on the .net side to just be mm/dd/yyyy  .net throws an error because the datetime coming in has the HH:MI on it.  The simplest solution I think is to just use 12:00 AM as the time as it'll work on both sides

Comment: I don't know C#, but in the database, `to_date(x, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM')` expects a string (not a date) like `01/23/2018 12:34 AM`. Is that what you have in the Oracle view? What is the error?

Comment: It is wrong when you say "The Oracle date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`" A DATE itself does not have any format in Oracle. You define the default **presentation format** with your session parameters. If you get a `DATE` value (rather that a string) from Oracle database then it is up to .NET application to format it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're retrieving a date field with no time data, and need it as a string in this format, try this: `to_char({0}, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM')`

If these date fields *do* have time data and you wish to show them all as 12:00 AM, then try this: `to_char(trunc({0}), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM')`